# How to Add assertion in monkey runner

Tags: monkeyrunner

I need to add couple of assertions on the screen.

Lets Say I am on Page 1. I need to verify that some xxx text is displayed or not and button is displayed or not and also need to verify that the label of the button.

Please Help me how to add assertion in the monkey runner script..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Monkeyrunner doesn't have its own assertion mechanisms that would suit your need. 
You can take a snapshot of your device and use some external image processing mechanism to verify interesting parts - but I know that wouldn't be ideal for text comparison. 
You can use Python Imaging Library http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: I am new to this.. How to use Python Imaging Library?...The link which you shared has exe only.. Please share any doc

Comment: This is a python's library so you have to use it like a typical library from tihs environment. Under the link that I gave here there is i.e. Python Imaging Library 1.1.7 Source Kit (all platforms) package. Just unpack it ($ tar xvfz Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz
        $ cd Imaging-1.1.7
        $ python setup.py install) and follow the instruction in the readme file. But if you're not familiar with the python you'll need to read some about it first.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyImage.html, if you already have a MonkeyImage object that looks correct you can use MonkeyImage.sameAs() to compare it to the current MonkeyImage.

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html might be helpful for saving MonkeyImage objects. (I'd like to stress the might though)

The next version of the SDK should have a method of loading MonkeyImage objects from image files so you can compare it with less work. See https://review.source.android.com//#change,21478 for more info about this change.